# ChangeNotifierProvider, child VS builder?

Tags: flutter

What is the difference between the child and the builder argument in ChangeNotifierProvider? How do you decide which one to use to build it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get hold of the `BuildContext` from which you can read the created provider, then you can use the `builder` property. It is just a "convenience function".

If you don't need it, then the `child` property can be used.